# Setting the selected attribute on an option element for real using jQuery

Tags: jquery, select, attributes

I am generating a select list with option elements in jQuery. Simplified it looks like this:

```
var sel = $("<select>");
$.each(data, function(i, v){
    $("<option>").attr({ "value": i }).html(v).appendTo(sel);
});
```

Then I want an option to be selected. Normally I would do something like:

```
$(sel).val(1);
```

But then the option does not have the selected attribute present.

`$(sel).html()` gives something like:

```
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
```

and this is what I expected:

```
<option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
```

I tried this approach (same result as using .val()):

```
$.each(data, function(i, v){
    var attrs = { "value": i };
    if(i == 1){
        attrs.selected = "selected";
    }
    $("<option>").attr(attrs).html(v).appendTo(sel);
});
```

but the only way I found working is:

```
$.each(data, function(i, v){
    var el = "<option>";
    if(i == 1){
        el = '<option selected="selected"></option>';
    }
    $(el).attr({ "value": i }).html(v).appendTo(sel);
});
```

Is there any other or better way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the [native `setAttribute()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute). I believe jQuery muddles the distinction between attributes and properties.

This gets the `<option>` you want by its index from the [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/select) element's [`options collection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLOptionsCollection), and sets the attribute:

```
sel[0].options[1].setAttribute('selected','selected');
```

Or this uses jQuery to set the value first, then goes back and gets the correct option using the [native `selectedIndex` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Property/selectedIndex).

```
sel.val(1);
sel[0].options[sel[0].selectedIndex].setAttribute('selected','selected');
```

---

**EDIT:** Off topic a little, but you could create the `<option>` elements a little differently like this:

```
$("<option>",{
    value: i,
    html: v
}).appendTo(sel);
```

Since jQuery 1.4, you can send a collection of values you wish to set for a new element.

Comment: Checked the jQuery source and attr intercepts when selected is found and uses selectedIndex as well. Thanks for the answer - easy to forget that there was a time before jQuery :)