# how to receive selected option on the same php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I need to display the content(per page) based on the option(per page) selected by the user

for which i need the selected option value in the same php page to display the content

but i cannot receive the value in php code ,Kindly give some solution to this problem

I've tried
 [Pass Javascript variable to PHP via ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461786/pass-javascript-variable-to-php-via-ajax)
 http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_get2
 http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_option_value

HTML Code for selecting option :

```
     <select id="page_count" >                                          
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
     </select>
```

JavaScript when option changed :

```
     var total_items;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#page_count").change(function(){
                var x = document.getElementById("page_count").selectedIndex;                    
                total_items=document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value;
                alert(total_items);
```

AJAX for posting the selected option :

```
            $.ajax({

                        type : "POST",                  
                        url : "start_landing_page.php",                                     
                        data : {total_items: total_items},                  
                        success : function(data){
                                alert("sucess!");
                                }
                        });
```

received via AJAX in php :

```
           <?php 
              if(isset($_POST['total_items'])){                 
                $uid = $_POST['total_items'];
                var_dump($uid);
                  } 
               >
```

Comment: `i cannot receive the value in php code` Where you could check?

Comment: your code looks ok. What exactly is the error ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790668/add-selected-attribute-to-option-in-select-menu-with-jquery

Comment: You have the `$.ajax` call right in the `change` handler, right?

Comment: vinay and ranjith thanks for you reply i can't receive the value to the variable in php $uid

Comment: jcaron thanks for you reply ,its inside that change handler only

Comment: I'm getting the value of javascript to php on $var_dump ,how to use that value with php variable within a same page

Comment: Check this fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/LL395Lze/

Answer (score 0):

The POST request should send data like this:

```
    data : 'total_items='+encodeURIComponent(total_items),
```

Comment: I'm getting the value of javascript to php on $var_dump ,how to use that value with php variable within a same page

Answer (score 0):

I feel you can use many options to get and pass the value, following is the simplest way you can access the selected value and pass it in your ajax function:

```
$("#page_count").change(function(e){
 total_items = $(this).val();
 ....
 ...
});
```

Full Example: [Jquery Receive selected option and Passing it in Ajax by using $.param()](http://jsfiddle.net/austinnoronha/v5V5A/)

Comment: Hi Austin thank you , but i need the javascript variable value on the same page via php variable to display content from server

Comment: Yes exactly you will need to pass the values in query format in your ajax function and then you can access the value in PHP via $_POST @madhavan   `var queryParams = {"total_items": total_items};
    //in ajax use dataParams in data parameter
    var dataParams = $.param(queryParams);` and in PHP `echo $_POST["total_items"]` . Check out my example for more info.

Comment: Austin The value came which i checked it via inspect element > network > preview  total_items=20 but i cannot use that value in my for loop

Comment: Could you give an example for the same